# Content Security Policy is preventing codes inside my JQuery Script

Tags: jquery, content-security-policy

Here are my policies in JSP code:

[image]

I am using the following scripts that have a CSP:

> nonce

```
<script src="/xx/xxxxxx/jquery-x.x.x.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="<%=nonce%>"></script>
<script src="/xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="<%=nonce%>"></script>
```

Result in Chrome:

[image]

When I try to click the error, I see 2 errors in jQuery file
(Note that the 2 errors below is not my code but from jquery.x.x.x.js)

First is:

[image]

Second is :

[image]

Now, how should I fix the 2 issues without using this CSP?

> unsafe-inline

A lot is saying the above and unsafe-eval is not advisable to use such as this: https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/47-how-to-prevent-the-use-of-unsafe-inline-in-csp

Answer (score 0):

## For the first error:

The `innerHTML` of the `div` you are inserting at runtime contains an `<a>` element with a `style` attribute. This is a [violation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src#Violation_cases) of your CSP, as this particular tag does not have a nonce.

#### Solution

It is unwise to use a nonce for this tag, as it is inserted at runtime, and the nonce should be added to the HTML server side.

I would recommend moving the CSS to another file and including the file using a link tag

HTML:

```html
<!-- Other html -->

<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

style.css

```
a#someId {
  color: red;
  float: left;
  opacity: .55;
}
```

Note that your JS would require some modification as the created `<a>` tag need to have an `id` attribute to be selected by CSS

script.js

```
div.style.display = "none";
div.innerHTML = "   <link/><table></table><a href='/a' id='someID' >a</a><input type='checkbox'/>"
```

## For the second error:

It's impossible to be certain what caused the error without knowing what are the contents of the script. Please post a few lines of code that is related to the creation of the script variable.

However, it is probably a similar issue with the first. A simple solution would be to move the dynamically appended scripts to another file and include that file with a script tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have updated my original question. The errors i mentioned are from jquery file, not mine

Comment: It would help if we could see which lines of the jquery file the errors are from

Comment: Again thanks for the interest - if you could go back to original question - it is itself the **First is:** and **Second is:**

Comment: I see. What version of jQuery are you using, and are you using any other jQuery plugins?

Comment: I am using version 1.4.2 - I tried using a newer version of jquery (1.9.1) and it fixed it (sorry I did not put this in the original question), but I have an old jqtouch (this one I am having troubles updating) that needs this old jquery version :-( .

Comment: Is there a problem with updating jqtouch? If so, maybe you could ask another question about that.